# Creating modal using bootstrap 4.1 in ASP.NET MVC 4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm very, very new to .net or any kind of backend developing - I've seen other questions, but couldn't use it to my project.

I need a simple modal that opens an Iframe.

1 - I have created the modal main container in the index.cshtml

2 - I added the link action. Here I also added the "data-target" and "data-toggle" that is usual to activate bootstrap modal.

3 - I Created a cotroller do return the view.

Then, when I click at the action link the usual modal layer appears, but without de modal content.
[image]

And when I remove the "data-target" and "data-toggle" it takes me tothe actual modal page.
[image]

So I think I'm missing something here, or I did not understand what else I need to do.

1 - In the main layout -> index.cshtml the modal container

```
 <div class="fade modal" id=exampleModalLabel aria-hidden=true aria-labelledby=exampleModalLabel role=dialog tabindex=-1>
     <div class=modal-dialog role=document>
         <div class=modal-content></div>
     </div>
 </div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("[role=dialog]").on("show.bs.modal", function (a) {
            $(this).find("[role=document]").removeClass().addClass("modal-dialog " + $(a.relatedTarget).data("ui-class"))
        })
    })
</script>
```

2 - My controller

```
 public ActionResult Modal()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

3 - My action link

```
<li class="dropdown ">
    @Html.ActionLink("Atendimento", "Modal", "Home", new { }, new
       {
         data_toggle = "modal",
         data_target = "#exampleModalLabel"
       })
</li>
```

4 - My modal.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}


<body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Atendimento Online</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>

<div class="modal-body">

    <style>
        #loading {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/Content/img/preloader.gif")");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .modal-body {
            background: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="pge">
        <iframe name="iframeaten" src="LOCATION-HERE" height="100vh" width="100%" marginheight="0" style=" margin:0;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="loading"></div>
    <script>
        function onReady(callback) {
            var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 4000);

            function checkReady() {
                if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                    callback.call(this);
                }
            }
        }

        function show(id, value) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

        onReady(function () {
            show('pge', true);
            show('loading', false);
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn standard lightgrey" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was trying the Hard way, I just needed to insert de modal content into the main container, since I did not neet to do any partial view.

```
<div class="fade modal" id=exampleModalLabel aria-hidden=true aria-labelledby=exampleModalLabel role=dialog tabindex=-1>
    <div class=modal-dialog role=document>
        <div class=modal-content>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Atendimento Online</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <style>
        #loading {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/Content/img/preloader.gif")");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .modal-body {
            background: #fff;
        }
                </style>
       <div id="pge">
       <iframe name="CONTEN_HERE" height="100vh" width="100%" marginheight="0" style=" margin:0;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
       </div>
    <div id="loading"></div>
 <script>
    function onReady(callback) { var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 4000);
    function checkReady() { if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) { 
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    callback.call(this);
      }
     }
   }
    function show(id, value) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
                                    }
      onReady(function () {
                                        show('pge', true);
                                        show('loading', false);
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn standard lightgrey" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```